# Metro WebServices on CloudFoundry

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, cloud-foundry

I want to deploy my Jax-WS2.2 based application on CloudFoundry tomcat instance.

In my local development environment, as I am using JDK6 I created endorsed directories in JRE/lib and CATALINA_HOME and copied jaxws-api.jar and jaxb-api.jar into endorsed dirs to resolve jaxws version conflicts and it is working fine.

But how can I do this while deploying onto CloudFoundry?

-Siva

Comment: What do you mean by conflict? Are you meaning to say to resolve dependency?

Comment: My JDK1.6 installation comes with some older JAX-WS. Now I am trying to use latest version of JAX-WS(Metro).

Comment: I would add them as POM dependency and deploy to CF. How do you handle the same in Eclipse while developing?? Have you tried deploying to CF at all?

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my question. Assume I have JDK1.6.22 which comes with (suppose)JAX-WS-2.0.1. Now If I want to create some webservices using JAX-WS-2.1.6 then I should replace the JDK1.6.22's JAX-WS jars(jaxb-api.jar, jaxws-api.jar) with JAX-WS-2.1.6(Metro) Jars because the JDK's JAXWS jars will be loaded first..not the JAXWS jar's in WEB-INF/lib.(correct me if i am wrong). So in my local environment I have access to my JDK installation dir and I am doing it. What if the same thing has to do on CloudFoundry as I don't have access to their JDK?

Comment: Yeah I got your question completely! All I am saying is CF is a different environment than your traditional Tomcats, so go ahead and try a sample application. If you see an error, raise a ticket for CF support and they will give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override jars provided in the JRE with your own (Unless you have access to the JRE which you don't on cf.com)

This cannot be done at this time.

You can however open a request at http://cloudfoundry.atlassian.net
in the Frameworks & Runtime-Java section.